# Difference between Array.from() and normal initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any difference in initializing array using Array.from([arrayElements]) and
var <variable_name>=[arrayElements].

If yes, when to use Array.from()? I suppose we use Array.from() when some kind of a transformation is needed to be applied on the array elements.. But for any transaformation we can use [Arrayelements].map(mappingFn) which I think eliminates the need of Array.from()? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What is `[arrayElements]`? An array *literal*? It would be better if you gave a concrete example.

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) - "The Array.from() static method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an iterable or array-like object." I guess don't use it if this is not what you want.

Comment: As to your second paragraph: you cannot call `.map` on an object that does not have that method, while `Array.from` is able to take any iterable or an object with a `length` property.

Comment: The difference is semantic basically. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452420/what-is-the-difference-between-condensed-arrays-and-literal-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same. Here is a snippet that shows one essential difference: `Array.from` returns a **new** array:

```js
const source = [1,2,3];
const arr1 = source;
const arr2 = Array.from(source);
console.log(arr1 === source); // True
console.log(arr2 === source); // False
```

Here are some reasons why to use `Array.from`:

1. When you need a new array, not the original array.

   This can be important when you want to make some changes to the array, like adding elements, removing elements, reordering elements, ..., but don't want to affect the original array. A practical example is returning a sorted array, without affecting the order of the input array:

   ```js
   const source = ["b", "d", "a", "c"];
   const arr2 = Array.from(source).sort();
   console.log(source); // Not sorted
   console.log(arr2); // sorted
   ```
2. When your input is an **iterable**, but you need to have an array

   For instance, you have a `Set`, but need it as an array:

   ```js
   const source = new Set;
   source.add(9).add(3).add(2);
   const arr1 = source; // This is no good -- I need an array!
   const arr2 = Array.from(source); // aha!
   console.log(arr2);
   ```
3. For the previous cases you can also use `[...source]`, but there is still a case to be made for `Array.from` when you need to **map** the iterated values with some transformation. In case you call `[...source].map(transform)` there is an intermediate array created (as a result of the spread syntax) which can be avoided with `Array.from`, because it has its own callback argument:

   ```js
   const source = new Set;
   source.add(1).add(2).add(3);

   const arr1 = [...source].map(a => a * 2); // OK
   const arr2 = Array.from(source, a => a * 2); // OK

   console.log(arr1);
   console.log(arr2);
   ```
4. When the input is an array-like object, but not an array, and I need an array. For instance `{ 0: 2, 1: 9, length: 2 }`

   ```js
   const arrayLike = { 0: 2, 1: 5, length: 2 };
   const arr1 = arrayLike;
   const arr2 = Array.from(arrayLike);
   console.log(arr1); // no
   console.log(arr2); // yes!
   ```
5. Not really a separate case, but a combination of the previous points makes it possible to create an array "on the fly" from an object literal that only has a `length` property, and the array contents follow some logic for which no other input is needed. For instance, the first ten multiples of 5:

   ```js
   const arr2 = Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => (i + 1) * 5);
   console.log(arr2);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One difference between using array literals `const x = [elements]` or  `const x = new Array(elements)` and `Array.from()` is, that the Array.from method can be used to create an array from **arrayLike/iterable objects** (while new Array() or using array literals requires you to pass a deconstructed (spread) array)

(additionally you can pass Array.from() a map Function - which will work quite similar to the array.map method)

> More clearly, Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg) has the same result as Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg), except that it does not create an intermediate array, and mapFn only receives two arguments (element, index) without the whole array, because the array is still under construction.
>
> Note: This is especially important for certain array subclasses, like
> typed arrays, since the intermediate array would necessarily have
> values truncated to fit into the appropriate type.

from mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

So Array.from() has its use cases (otherwise it would not have been implemented as its own method), but unless you need it I would suggest sticking to the traditional ways of creating arrays.

Answer (score -1):

While selected elements using the `getElementsByClassName`, all the array methods cannot be used as it isn't a proper array.

By using `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('el'))`, all array methods like forEach, reduce, map are available. I mainly used this for looping through all elements with a same class name.

I suppose `[arrayElements]` is valid but looking at the syntax, it seems like all the elements are just put into a new array where all array methods work.